# Binding dynamic select list with asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel of a form (Name, Address) etc and it's all bound to controls on my page (using Spark engine) - e.g.

```
!{ Html.DropDownList() }
```

That works fine. However, there is one DropDownList which is bound that has no values in it to begin with, the values are populated using Ajax (by selecting previous drop downs)

The problem lies when I submit the page and there's a validation error. The page loads and my select list has no values in it (as it hasn't been triggered to get them).

How can I set it up so that the ViewModel knows about values got dynamically so that it can populate the select list on page load?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the validation error?

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to:

Do this server side by using the Html.DropDownList() call that allows you to pass values in:

```
Html.DropDownList(string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
```

Or the other way would be to just trigger the same ajax call when the page loads so you don't have duplicated logic.

I'd actually recommend the second way, as it'll keep you from doing the same thing multiple ways, but it does mean that there'

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property of selectlist type in your viewmodel, populate it in constructor, and call it through Html.DropDownList function in your view page. Further since this selectlist is dependent on another list(i.e another property of you viewmodel). in your constructor you can write code like,

say if first listbox is connected to list1 property of type int and allowed values are >0

```
<code>
if (list1!=0)
{
   write code to populate second list based on your first list parameter and also set 
   the selected value as if selected by the user at submit its stored in the other 
   property linked to the second list box.
}
</code>
```

if you are still not clear, write here the concerned code of your viewmodel, and server side database call of your second list, I may help you by editing your code.